# How to get the TreeNode under mouse cursor when the mouse is down?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

Basically the TreeView has checkboxes, and I am able to get the TreeNode, but it gives me the TreeNode wherever I click on the TreeNode, from it's text to it's checkbox and a little beyond that (to the left).

Can I restrict the hittest so I only get a TreeNode if the user click on the checkbox of the TreeNode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don´t really know what you want to do but you might be able to use TreeView event BeforeCheck or AfterCheck.

BeforeCheck has TreeViewCancelEventArgs as argument and TreeViewCancelEventArgs have a Cancel property you can use if you don´t want the checkbox to change state.

Edit:
Some thing like this might work...

```
        private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _lastNode = null;
            _mouseDown = true;
        }

        private void treeView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_mouseDown)
            {
                var hitTestInfo = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);
                if (hitTestInfo.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage 
                   && hitTestInfo.Node != _lastNode)
                {
                    _lastNode = hitTestInfo.Node;
                    hitTestInfo.Node.Checked = !hitTestInfo.Node.Checked;
                }
                else
                {
                    _lastNode = null;
                }
            }
        }

        private void treeView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _lastNode = null;
            _mouseDown = false;
        }
```

Comment: It's hard to explain but I am looking for a way to check/uncheck tree nodes if you click and drag over a treenode checkbox. So if you click over a tree node and drag over several checkboxes, it would toggle them all as you go over them while your left mouse button is down. I got it all working except once you start dragging, the dragging can also go outside the checkbox square, and still toggles the treenodes.

Comment: TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage was what I was looking for.